# Cannot access to spring boot application running with docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kotlin, docker-compose, mariadb

I have a simple application composed by spring boot and mariadb. OS is mac OS, and using IntelliJ as IDE. Dockerfile for spring app is below;

```
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
VOLUME /app

ENV JAR_TARGET "my_app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java -jar ./build/libs/${JAR_TARGET}"]
```

And docker-compose.yml which refers Dockerfile above is like;

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  app:
    build: docker/.
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      spring.datasource.driverClassName: "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
      spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:mariadb://db:3306/my_app_db"
      spring.datasource.username: "user"
      spring.datasource.password: "password"
      server.port: 8080
      server.address: 127.0.0.1

  db:
    image: mariadb
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=my_app_db
      - MYSQL_USER=user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword,
```

By typing the command `docker-compose up --build` into terminal, docker-compose starts runnning and spring boot app "my_app" also seems to be running with the log `... Started MyAppApplicationKt in 25.161 seconds (JVM running for 27.301)`.

However, when I try to access that spring app by calling `http://localhost:8080/api`, it is not responding. For example, when I do `curl` with the address, it is timed out every time. I checked with IP `127.0.0.1` too, but it resulted in the same; not responding.

When I see `docker container ps`, both spring app and mariadb look like successfully running as below.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
b6abb2d330d9        my_app        "sh -c 'java -jar -D…"   5 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   my_app_1
fb3b3cad20ad        mariadb       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 minutes ago      Up 5 minutes        0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp   my_app_db_1
```

I cannot understand why this spring app is not responding when I reach `http://localhost:8080/api`. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Which OS are you using ? If using VirtualBox under Windows, don't forget to forward your ports (8080 in your case).

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for checking. I am using Mac OS with IDE intellij. Added OS information to the question description.

Comment: Do you have such an active profile `-Dspring.profiles.active=docker-compose`? do you have a `application-docker-compose.yml` or `application-docker-compose.properties` file?

Comment: Hi Stefan, thank you for checking. 
I forgot deleting the part `-Dspring.profiles.active=docker-compose` as I do not have an active profile anymore. Deleted that part from the above question.
 I do not have `application-docker-compose.yml` nor `application-docker-compose.properties`, although I have general `application.properties`. Do you think this could be causing the issue?

Comment: Do you need to set `server.address` to `0.0.0.0`?  Generally if a process inside a Docker container is listening on `127.0.0.1`, it won't be reachable from outside its container.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your comment. As the answer I posted below, I changed `server.address` to `0.0.0.0` from `127.0.0.1`, and it started listening on `127.0.0.1` for access from outside. Thank you so much for your knowledge and experience!

Answer (score 1):

[David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze)'s comment did solve my problem. The docker container was not listening on `127.0.0.1` because I set inside process address on `127.0.0.1`. I changed `server.address` in docker-compose.yml to `0.0.0.0`, and it started listening on `127.0.0.1` for outside access.
Thank you so much for all comments, especially David who saved me!